# What kind of trinitarian was Thomas F. Torrance?

Tags: trinity, reformed-theology, thomas-f-torrance

If I understand correctly (and I might be wrong). When it comes to the doctrine of the Trinity, as **opposed** to the [Cappadocian Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappadocian_Fathers#:%7E:text=The%20Cappadocian%20Fathers%2C%20also%20traditionally,who%20became%20Patriarch%20of%20Constantinople.) (or at lest against Basil), Torrance believed that not just God the Father *alone* should be identified as the Godhead, but rather, the undivided Trinity.

I know there are different trinitarian models that modern Christians subscribe today like: [Social Trinitarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_trinitarianism#:%7E:text=The%20social%20trinitarianism%20is%20a,is%20an%20inherently%20social%20being.), [Subordinationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinationism), etc.

I was wondering if Torrance's views fall under one category, if it has a name, namely the idea that the Godhead is to be identified with all three persons.

Comment: I've never heard that Basil thought only the Father was the Godhead. Got any more sources for that? I would've said that the idea that the Godhead is the nature of all three persons is standard Nicene Trinitarianism.

Comment: @curiousdannii AFAIK, yes, but God the Father alone is without "cause" (arche)
See:
https://www.faith-theology.com/2017/06/filioque-letter-to-australia-from-tf.html

Comment: That's an interesting letter! Before asking what kind of Trinitarianism Torrance taught, it might be better to ask if his explanation of the Cappadocians is accurate. There is a lot of debate over the filioque of course, and both sides have equal right to be called full Nicene Trinitarians.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149505/discussion-between-dan-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: I have basic familiarity with these church fathers, but not enough to give a detailed response. In any case, I would say I'm pretty sure the historical position is no causality and the Godhead being the nature of all three. In those respects Torrance would be typical. The Cappadocians may be slightly atypical, as was often the case for trailblazers in theology.